# Show the limit of the characteristic function is zero a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X$ be a measurable space, in which $C$ is a $\sigma$-ring of measurable sets, with $\mu$ as the measure. Let $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of sets in $C$. Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n) < +\infty$. Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \chi_{A_n} = 0$ almost everywhere on $X$.

Here, $\chi_{A_n}$ is the characteristic function for $A_n$.

Idea: So, it's immediate that you get $\mu(A_n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. This implies that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \int_X \chi_{A_n} d\mu = 0$$.

From here, I think you can use Fatou's lemma somehow? That gets you this:

$$\int_X \liminf \chi_{A_n} d\mu \leq \liminf \int_X \chi_{A_n} d\mu = 0$$

using the fact that convergence of $\mu(A_n)$ implies we have convergence of the $\liminf$ to the same limit. But now I'm stuck. I was thinking you could somehow do something with the limsup, but I'm not sure. And if you had convergence of $\chi_{A_n}$, then you could just use DCT I think.

Comment: Notice that $\limsup\mathbf{1}_{A_n}(x)=1$ if and only if there are infinitely many $n$'s for which $x\in A_n$. Now let $$N(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbf{1}_{A_n}(x)$$ and notice that $N(x)$ counts the number of $n$'s for which $x\in A_n$, hence $\limsup\mathbf{1}_{A_n}(x)=1$ if and only if $N(x)=\infty$. Now using the condition $\int_X N\,d\mu<\infty$, you can conclude that this happens only on a $\mu$-measure-zero set.

Comment: This is a consequence of the Borel-Cantelli lemma, which you can read about [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel–Cantelli_lemma).

Comment: I see how how it works now. Thank you @SangchulLee. Is there a way I can credit you with an answer, or should I answer my own question with the proof?

Comment: Glad it helped! Anyway, I realized that this question is an almost duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2146213/show-int-x-limsup-limits-n-to-infty-mathbb1-a-n-d-mu-0-for-sum-n-i?rq=1, which makes me reluctant to write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Read the proof of the first Borel-Cantelli Lemma.